# Having trouble combining an API .JAR into my .JAR app. JAR within a JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

**Disclaimer:**
 
*Before I get the standard "this has been asked 1000 times", let me say that yes, I know. I have read and read and read. Looked at JarJar and One-JAR but the problem is: I am self-taught with only a couple of months of experience under me and I am not familiar with Ant or Maven or anything other than vanilla Java. I use NetBeans as my compiler, just to add.*

I have written an application for use at my job. It is just a small app that takes certain input and writes it to an Excel file. I downloaded jexcelapi (jxl.jar) and placed that appropriately. I have no trouble running the file inside of NetBeans or from within the dist/ folder after it is built. Therein lies the problem: if I move the app to, say, the Desktop, I get an error from the JVM saying "A Java Exception has occurred." I know that this is due to the fact that the *main* class is added to the .JAR automatically but to add another lib, I will have to make a "Class-path" statement within my Manifest. I tried that unsuccessfully. I have tried moving the actual jxl.jar file to my jdk folder and I tried calling the entire file path that points directly to the jxl.jar file into my Manifest. The closest I can get is building the .JAR in NetBeans and it adds the lib folder to the dist folder where the app .JAR is.

I want to distribute this app as just a single .JAR without having to send all the users a copy of the jexcelapi lib. It doesn't have to be a .JAR within a .JAR; it can be whatever way is easiest and simplest. As stated before, I am not familiar with Ant and One-Jar draws on that. I am still learning; can someone point me in the right direction with this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to forum. as I can see you have other 2 questions and none of they marked as accepted=> no reason to answer, because you don't know you should accept a solution if is good enough

Comment: "I am not familiar with Ant or Maven" it is time to start learning ANT, Netbeans use it later you need Maven too

Comment: @matheszabi not sure if I am missing sarcasm or what but I accepted answers to the previous questions right after posting this question. New to the forum, dully noted, so I'm learning how things are done here.

Comment: people who give answers to you, like me. Are "working" for reputations or for other. An accepted answers means 15 repu and 1x up-vote 10 repu, but this is the only one measurement what you got. It cost for you 2 seconds to do 2x click: upvote ( if you have 15 repu already ) and accept. If you accet an aswer, than you mark as "solved" and others who are searching the same question can jump directly to solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of exhausting search, I found something that was incredibly short, sweet, and right to the point. You cannot mess it up. Here is the [link](http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html).

Comment: +1 good point, I haven't worked with netbeans ages, this is a new feature for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a better one for novice programmers.

[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) gives what you need, even wraps it to exe file. Yu don't need to know programming at all to use this.

OFC there are ANT task if you ant to automatise the Launch4j , but for that you must leant a bit about ANT :)

Comment: Wow. If it does that and even converts it to an .exe file, that would be awesome. Gonna check it out.

Comment: @user2761628 your clients still needs JRE

Comment: of course. I sent one of my applications to a co-worker to test to see if their JRE would run the .JAR app. This was a different app, btw.

Comment: @Rincewind if this answer helped then press the Up vote pls :)

Comment: Still working on it. Having a little trouble with adding the additional .JAR into launch4j.

Comment: Launch4j has some nice bells and whistles. I will be adding a lot of neat stuff when I release revisions. Thank you for introducing me to that program!